# Swift - Change height of CollectionView Header

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, resize

I would like to change the height of the header of my `CollectionViewController`.

I already know that I could use a code like that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 250)
}
```

I would like to do that, but directly within the UICollectionReusableView (the header view).

Is there any function that allows that?

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change header size dynamically, use **headerReferenceSize** UICollectionViewFlowLayout property.

```
let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionViewLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 80)
```

Make sure **not** to include **referenceSizeForHeaderInSection** delegate method to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Headers in collectionview are diferent like tableview because you need to create diferent kind of cell, this cell is named `UICollectionReusableView`, create a class with this name and then in your collectionview check this option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6DTx.png)

and then you can call this on code with this function:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                             at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
  //1
  switch kind {
  //2
  case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
    //3
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                       withReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionReusableViewID",
                       for: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableViewClass
//Customize

    return headerView
  default:
    //4
    assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
  }
}
```

all the credits RayWenderLich tutorials : https://www.raywenderlich.com/1404-uicollectionview-tutorial-reusable-views-selection-and-reordering